# Struggling with iLib

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I've downloaded the current version (11.0) of the amazing-sounding iLib Javascript I18N library, to use for parsing international addresses. Unfortunately, I can't get off the blocks using it. The documentation says to load iliball.js, which isn't in the distribution or list of files on Github. Trying js/assembled/ilib-full-compiled.js instead, I'm able to:

```
% js
> var module = require("./ilib-full-compiled.js")
> module.ilib.getVersion()
'11.0.006'
```

but Address isn't defined in the module:

```
> module.Address("1234 Main Street\nDenver CO")
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Address'
    at repl:1:10
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

and similarly for module.ilib.Address.

Further, I can't find the "jsa" tool that would allow me to create my own assembled libraries. Further yet, trying to build from the iLib source generates a whole slew of errors.

It just can't be this hard to use this. What am I missing here? (I don't have the reputation points to create an "ilib" tag, so I'm hoping this comes to the attention of someone who's connected with the project.)

Comment: I just did `npm install -g ilib` and then when I `require("ilib")` I get an object that *does* have an `Address` function on it.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, but after doing so `require("ilib")` tells me that it can't find the module. `npm` installs the module into /usr/local/lib/node_modules. Is there a path variable somewhere that I have to set? *Edit*: Turns out there is. I would have thought that npm would install it somewhere that nodejs could find it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work with Go/Otto, but on nodejs, you can get one of the classes inside of ilib by use a trick with require to access it. Basically, add "ilib/lib/" + the class name to get it:

```
> var ilib = require("ilib");
> var Address = require("ilib/lib/Address");
> var add = new Address("1234 Main Street, Denver CO 80202");
> add
{ sync: true,
  loadParams: {},
  locale: 
   { language: 'en',
     region: 'US',
     script: undefined,
     variant: undefined,
     spec: 'en-US' },
  lines: undefined,
  country: undefined,
  countryCode: 'US',
  info: 
   { formats: 
      { default: '{streetAddress}\n{locality} {region} {postalCode}\n{country}',
        nocountry: '{streetAddress}\n{locality} {region} {postalCode}' },
     startAt: 'end',
     fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  compare: [ [Function: Function] ],
  postalCode: '80202',
  region: 'CO',
  locality: 'Denver',
  streetAddress: '1234 Main Street' }
```

Alternately, the object returned in the require will contain an Address class, but you should use "new" with it to create a new instance:

```
var module = require("ilib");
new module.Address("1234 Main Street\nDenver CO");
```

The resulting instance has a few methods on it as well as the parsed properties.

More details on the ilib wiki: https://sourceforge.net/p/i18nlib/wiki/New%20Modularization%20Support/

As for npm, when you install locally instead of globally, it will find the node_modules without needing to set your path.

For assembling your own ilib, you need a few things installed first:

- Oracle Java JDK 1.7 or later
- Apache ant
- Nodejs 0.10
- npm

Once they are all there in the path, rolling your own version of ilib  should go a lot more smoothly. Jsa is a java-based tool, the source code to which is in ilib. Ant compiles this first and then uses it to assemble ilib. (One day I'll rewrite it for nodejs.)